# openxlsx conditional formatting with multiple rules

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I would like to format some cells in Excel using openxlsx using multiple rules. For example, here the result 3 should not be highlighted as the criteria is `NA`. I am comparing the result cell to the criteria cell. Is there a way of using two rules to format cells? I tried with different combinations of `&` and quotation marks but couldn't get it to work.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

# data -----------
df <- tibble(result = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             criteria = c(0.5, 5, NA, 2, 6))

# formatting Style
yellow <- createStyle(fontColour= "#000000", bgFill = "#FFBF3F")

# create Excel workbook
wb <-createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", df) 

# format
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet 1",
                      cols = 1,
                      rows = 2:(nrow(df)+1),
                      type = "expression",
                      rule = "> $B2", 
                      style = yellow)

# view
openXL(wb)
```

[image]

This is the desired output:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~result, ~criteria,                         ~desired,
        1,       0.5, "Highlighted as is greater than",
        2,         5,   "Less than so not highlighted",
        3,        NA,          "NA so not highlighted",
        4,         2, "Highlighted as is greater than",
        5,         6,   "Less than so not highlighted"
  )
```

Comment: `For example, here the result 3 should not be highlighted as the criteria is NA.` Will the cell have NA or is blank? Screenshot shows blank cell in B4. Anyways, in MS Excel, I would have used the formula `=AND($A2>$B2,$B2<>"")` instead of `> $B2`. See if that works for you? For NA the formula becomes `=AND($A2>$B2,$B2<>"NA")`

Comment: Great. That works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by keeping NA true we can get the desired result

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

# data -----------
df <- tibble(result = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             criteria = c(0.5, 5, NA, 2, 6),)

# formatting Style
yellow <- createStyle(fontColour= "#000000", bgFill = "#FFBF3F")

# create Excel workbook
wb <-createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", df,keepNA = TRUE) 

# format
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet 1",
                      cols = 1,
                      rows = 2:(nrow(df)+1),
                      type = "expression",
                      rule = ">$B2", 
                      style = yellow)

# view
openXL(wb)
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is there something that would work for multiple conditions though? Do you know how that syntax works?

Comment: Actually, I think @Siddharth Rout's comment seems to work for this.